# Passing Parameter into single Quoted TSQL Script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to Print this script into below format

Result i want should be

```
EXEC dbo.MyProc ' -n mssql -a "myname=myusers" -a "name2=name2" -a "SHOST=9.9.9.9" -a "computername=@sName" -k'
```

My Query is

```
USE [master]    
GO    
Declare @SName varchar(100),  
        @sql varchar(max)   
Set @SName='myservername'   
Set @sql= EXEC dbo.MyProc '-n mssql -a "myname=myusers" -a "name2=name2" -a "SHOST=9.9.9.9" -a "computername=@sName" -k'   
Print @sql
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The reason you don't have an answer yet is because you haven't yet finished your question. You see, as posted this just doesn't have enough information for others to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [master] 
GO 
Declare @SName varchar(100),
    @sql varchar(max) 

Set @SName='servername'

Set @sql= 'EXEC dbo.MyProc '' -n mssql -a "myname=myusers" -a "name2=name2" -a "SHOST=9.9.9.9" -a "computername=@sName" -k'''

 Print @sql
```

Comment: Thanks but how I can replace sName as myservername